# Gcloud repository - how to make a repo stable?

Tags: google, repository, gcloud, composer

We're using our gcloud cloud repositories to store modules and themes for our project which we get with composer. But I can't find a way to make a repository labelled as "stable" for this purpose; I always get this error:

> Could not find a version of package [packagename] matching your
>   minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version
>   constraint allowing its desired stability.

Sure enough it works if I explicitly state that it should take the `dev-master` but that feels like a workaround and I would assume Cloud Repositories have some functionality to set a stable state, right?

Answer (score 0):

Google Source Repositories (GSR) are a git based repositories and for that reason the behavior and the main capabilities needs to be implemented like any other git based solution (github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc ...), GSR doesn’t have a special function to mark stable code in composer.

But I think that is directly related with composer and how to mark your code as stable, you can use [TAGS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags) [ALIAS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md) or [stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#minimum-stability) to mark your module instead a branch.

There is [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer) about the use of the TAGS in composer.